# Bianchi Identity - Gauge Theory

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms, vector-bundles, gauge-theory

I am reading through some lecture notes (found [here](http://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/GT/Lect2.pdf)) and following a proof of the Bianchi identity in the context of principal bundles. That is,

$h^*\Omega = 0$, where $\Omega$ is the curvature 2-form of the connection and $h^*$ is the map defined as

$h^*\beta(X_1,\dots,X_k)=\beta(hX_1,\dots,hX_k)$ where $hX_i$ are the horizontal components of the vector fields $X_i\in TP$.

I do not understand a line in the working on page 14

$d\left(\frac{1}{2}[\omega,\omega]\right)=\frac{1}{2}[d\omega,\omega]-\frac{1}{2}[\omega,d\omega]$

I am struggling to undersand 2 things:

1) How does the exterior derivative $d$ explicitly act on the 2 form $[\omega,\omega]$,

2) How does the 3 form $[d\omega,\omega]$ act on a triple of vector fields $(X,Y,Z)$?

I cannot seem to equate the two questions above given the definitions I have found from various resources on the internet, say, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra-valued_differential_form)

Comment: 2) The definition given in that wikipedia article is correct, though your source may or may not use the factor of $\frac{1}{(p+q)!}$. It seems (based on your equation) that it probably doesn't. I'll assume not.
1) $[\omega, \omega](v_1, v_2) = 2[\omega(v_1),\omega(v_2)]$. If in coordinates $\omega = \sum f_i dx_i$, where $f_i$ are Lie algebra valued smooth functions, then verify $[\omega, \omega]$ is $2\sum [f_i, f_j] dx_i \wedge dx_j$. Now that we're in coordinates, we can just apply $d$ and see what it does.